# Traefik yml acme email value from environment variables

Tags: docker, yaml, environment-variables, traefik

I use a compose file with two services (Python app & Traefik), in the docker file I load all the environment variables.

For Traefik I use a YML file to define the services, In that YML file I have a node for certificateResolvers, that node looks like this:

```
certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    acme:
      email: "email@domain.com"
      storage: /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web
```

I want to set the email from a environment variable so the YML file should looks like this:

```
certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    acme:
      email: '{{env "USER_EMAIL"}}'
      storage: /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web
```

Having the YML in this way I got this in the Logs:

```
level=info msg="Starting provider *acme.Provider {\"email\":\"{{env \\\"USER_EMAIL\\\"}}\",\"caServer\":\"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"storage\":\"/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json\",\"keyType\":\"RSA4096\",\"httpChallenge\":{\"entryPoint\":\"web\"},\"ResolverName\":\"letsencrypt\",\"store\":{},\"ChallengeStore\":{}}"

level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"domain.com\": cannot get ACME client acme: error: 400 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-acct :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:invalidEmail :: Error creating new account :: \"{{env \\\"USER_EMAIL\\\"}}\" is not a valid e-mail address, url: " providerName=letsencrypt.acme routerName=web-secure-router@file rule="Host(`domain.com`)"
```

I tried with:

```
email: '{{env "USER_EMAIL"}}'
email: '`{{env "USER_EMAIL"}}`'
email: "{{env 'USER_EMAIL'}}"
email: "{{env USER_EMAIL}}"
```

But none of those worked.

In the same YML file I have a node that looks like this:

```
http:
  routers:
    web-secure-router:
      rule: 'Host(`{{env "PROJECT_HOSTNAME"}}`)'

      entryPoints:
        - web-secure
      service: fastapi
      tls:
        certResolver: letsencrypt
```

In that section, I get the right value of the `PROJECT_HOSTNAME` variable, in this case `domain.com` as you can see in the Logs above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this may not be the solution, but it is a different way of doing things, you can try with:

instead of using traefik yml, use commands in the docker compose yml;

[image: Example]

https://github.com/nasatome/docker-network-utils/blob/389324b6795d07684dac9bfe7dc5315bcd7eef7c/reverse-proxy/traefik/docker-compose.yml

Another thing to try would be to use:

```
${USER_EMAIL}
```

instead of

```
{{env "USER_EMAIL"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify on why you cannot use your own user defined environment variable for `certificatesResolvers` is because this is part of the [static configuration](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/reference/static-configuration/file/), whereas the `http` is part of the [dynamic configuration](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/reference/dynamic-configuration/file/) (where you can use your own like `PROJECT_HOSTNAME`)

You can still use `TRAEFIK` [Environment variables](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/reference/static-configuration/env/) to set the email for your certificate resolver with the variable `TRAEFIK_CERTIFICATESRESOLVERS_<NAME>_ACME_EMAIL`.

I haven't tested this myself, but I think the following should do the trick:

```yaml
services:
  traefik:
    environment:
       TRAEFIK_CERTIFICATESRESOLVERS_LETSENCRYPT_ACME_EMAIL: ${USER_EMAIL}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed all the configurations to the compose file, and yes then I realized that the certificates resolver section belongs to the static configuration.